# How is a Java program bound to the JDK?

Tags: java

I made a java program that I want to upload on a website. I want it to be available to download for everybody. I read many things about Oracle OpenJDK and OcacleJDK but I do not really know how this is connected to my program. And if I made my program with the Oracle JDK, how can I change it to work with the Oracle Open JDK?

Edit:
Sorry, I do not really know that much about JDK's and so on... That I understand this correct, the JDK is not bound to the program. The end user needs to have the JDK installed on the computer. Because I am not sure, if I need to buy a java license.

Comment: If you build a self-executable Jar file (with all third party dependencies inside or alongside), then anyone should be able to run it on their JVM whether it's OpenJDK or GraalVM or what.

Comment: Both those implementations meet the specs, so both can run it. The standard library's pretty much the same no matter which JDK you use (I'm not sure about JavaFX and internal APIs)

Comment: Sorry, I do not really know that much about JDK's and so on... That I understand this correct, the JDK is not bound to the programm. The end user needs to havbe the JDK installed on the computer. Because I am not shure, if I need to buy a java license.

Comment: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24048157/how-to-create-a-self-executing-jar-file

In summary a self-executing JAR is a Zip file with a MANIFEST.MF file with a "main class"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> And if I made my program with the Oracle JDK, how can I change it to work with the Oracle Open JDK?

No need to change it.

Understand that the Java platform is defined by a [set of specifications](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/). Any implementation that complies with those specs can run any Java-based app. To ensure compatibility, an implementation may be subjected to test suites published by Oracle ([TCK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technology_Compatibility_Kit)) or by Adoptium ([AQA](https://docs.google.com/document/d/16Xsou_sNgSoUI-Sr92Y0QSWO-QtYY09gbTGhtPecCEk/edit)).

If you write a Java app using an implementation of Java 11, for example, then that app can run on any other implementation of Java 11. And most likely, that app will run an any implementation of future versions of Java.

*Oracle JDK* is a product from Oracle that implements the [Java specifications](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/). This product is commercial, requiring a fee for use in production, with support available. Oracle also releases an unsupported free-of-cost product that is an implementation of Java that oddly does not exactly have a name, found [here](http://jdk.java.net).

Both of those products are built from the open-source project [OpenJDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK). Several other vendors also release implementations of Java based on this source code. You can build your app using any of these, and run your app using any of these.

Your use of the phrase “Oracle OpenJDK” is not accurate. While Oracle founded the project, and provided the bulk of the source code, the project is also backed by IBM, Apple, and others contributing important parts of the code base.

Here is a flowchart to help you in selecting a vendor. The products found inside the blue barrel are built entirely or nearly entirely from the source code provided by the OpenJDK project. The two products outside the barrel use parts of OpenJDK, but have significant portions built from other source code to provide their special features.

[image: Flowchart guiding you in choosing a vendor for a Java 11 implementation]

> I want it to be available to download for everybody.

Your app needs an implementation of Java to run.

- Your user can have an implementation of Java installed locally on their computer. Then you probably should build a [JAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_(file_format)) file containing your app for distribution.
- You can include an implementation of Java bundled inside of your app. See the *jlink* tool. You can then make a complete self-contained "double-clickable" app that runs like any other app. Search Stack Overflow to learn more.

> Because I am not sure, if I need to buy a java license.

Some of the Java implementations require a fee in some circumstances, and that also buys you support in all the cases I know of.

Some of the Java implementations are free-of-cost. Of course you do not get the benefits of paid support, unless you engage a support service company separately.

The key concept to remember is that the ***OpenJDK* project provides only source-code** but not binaries/installers. For binaries/installers, choose a vendor following the flowchart I posted above. For newbies wanting a free-of-cost implementation of Java, I suggest [Adoptium](https://adoptopenjdk.net) (formerly known as AdoptOpenJDK), as this is a cooperative effort involving nearly all of the other vendors.

[image: Motivations in choosing a vendor for Java]

> That I understand this correct, the JDK is not bound to the program.

True, your Java-based app is never bound to a JDK (Java implementation). After deployment, the Java implementation could be replaced by another while leaving your Java app untouched, no need to recompile. A [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) launches first, and then uses a [Java class loader](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Classloader) to load your app’s classes from your JAR file. A JVM is actually the app running on top of the host OS. On top of the JVM is your app running. So: host OS > JVM > your app classes.

This means your Java classes are *not* bound to the Java implementation, not in the sense of a [linker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_%28computing%29) in conventional software.

Caveat: What I discussed above is generally the case. GraalVM is very special in that it enables ahead-of-time compilation, for a different runtime situation. But that is cutting-edge technology, and not commonly used. [Project Leyden](https://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/discuss/2020-April/005429.html) is a possible similar effort.

---

I suggest reading the white paper [*Java Is Still Free*](https://medium.com/@javachampions/java-is-still-free-2-0-0-6b9aa8d6d244).